# Normalization in $L^{p}$ and $L^{q}$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Given a function $f$ in $L^{p}\cap L^{q}$  where $0<p,q<\infty$,
can $f$ always be normalized such that $\| f \|_p=\| f \|_q=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

For example take your measure space to be $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure. Take $f(x)=2x$, $p=1,q=2$. Then $||f||_p=1$. To normalize $f$ you can only multiply it by a constant- and that would disturb the $||.||_p$.

Comment: @user134927: That would fix the case for a single function, but there will be many others that will be "disturbed".

Answer (score 0):

For an even simpler counterexample, let $f(x)\equiv 0$.